# Why doesn't ResourceWriter generate a valid .resx file?

Tags: c#, .net, resx

I am trying to generate a .resx file from a C# program. When I open the generated file, I am getting data like below:

> *ÎÊï¾   ‘   lSystem.Resources.ResourceReader, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089#System.Resources.RuntimeResourceSet          PADPADP%†ÐÙ    Ï   C o n t a c t     Contact Information**

Here is the code that I am using to write to the file:

```
string resPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ResourcePath"];
var wr = new ResourceWriter(resPath);
wr.AddResource("Contact", "Contact Information");
wr.Generate();
wr.Close();
```

Comment: why do you think it is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong class. [ResourceWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcewriter(v=vs.110).aspx) creates a .resources file, not a .resx file. To create a .resx file, use [ResXResourceWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourcewriter(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
using (ResXResourceWriter writer = new ResXResourceWriter(resPath))
{
    writer.AddResource(new ResXDataNode("Contact", "Contact Information"));
}
```

**Note:** To use ResXResourceWriter, you must add an assembly reference to System.Windows.Forms.

Comment: While this answer is generally correct, I want to point out some caveats that go with it.

ResXResourceWriter is not part of .NET Standard, it requires you to take a dependency on System.Windows.Forms - which is annoying to say the least.